# How to Record Voice Using Superpowered Sdk in android

Tags: superpowered

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT void Java_com_superpowered_crossexample_MainActivity_onRecord(JNIEnv * __unused javaEnvironment, jobject __unused  obj ,jboolean jboolean1) {
    example->Record();
}
```

Comment: Which error , are you getting?

Comment: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x4d5f656c in tid 10988